# How to calculate the quiescent current of a common emitter amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, common-emitter

Given the supplied circuit - I'm trying to work how to calculate the quiescent current.

All values are known. I've already done it in SPICE but really would like to know what the formula looks like!

[image]

Comment: Where would YOU start? What do you think - which BJT parameters are important to know or to estimate?

Comment: Start by writing some KVLs, and at some point you'll need a few transistor-nature definitions.

Comment: I already spent half a day in this, got completely lost, hence why I'm here ;-)

Comment: Maybe start with the thevenin equivalent of R1 and R2, then look at the current in RE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my favourite interview question circuit, because it tests the interviewee's ability to reason, state assumptions, make good approximations, refine those approximations. And if they can handle the DC conditions, I can then go on to ask about AC.

Putting all the parameters into one honkin' big formula to arrive at the quiescent current is a particularly futile exercise in my book. It can be done, but it teaches you nothing.

What do we know about the transistor? We don't know its beta, but we expect it to be large, so let's make a simple assumption that it's infinite. Any real transistor circuit has to be designed to cope with a large beta variation anyway, so a first pass with a very large beta is a sensible thing to do.

- That means the base current is zero.
- Which means that we know the base voltage from the R1/R2 ratio.
- Let's make the simple assumption that the transistor 'turns on' at a VBE of 0.7 V.
- Which means we now know the emitter voltage.
- So we know the emitter current.

And we have now found the first approximation to the quiescent current. That current flowing through RL gives the collector voltage, so we now know everything.

Now we have a back-of-envelope solution for a very high gain transistor, we can refine it a little.

- Let's assume a finite beta, like 100.
- We found an approximation to the quiescent current in the first pass, so now we have an estimate of the base current.
- The base current is sourced from the R1/R2 divider. Compute the Thevenin source impedance of those, that's the output impedance of the divider.
- The voltage drop at the base is just the base current flowing through R1/R2's output impedance.
- Which gives us the new emitter voltage and quiescent current estimates.

Now we can find out whether our design is robust, or fragile. Have the changes in voltage due to a finite beta been small, or large? Small => good design, large => going to give you trouble.

It's worth doing a similar round of testing your design against the VBE assumption, as this parameter is also quite variable (at the 10s of mV level) between different transistors, and for temperature variations of the transistor. This is more important for low voltage rails than high voltage rails. Why?

Do you need to worry about Early voltage / transistor output impedance? Or maybe the diode model for VBE instead of a fixed voltage? I'm now retired, and have never once had to refine a bias circuit that far, beta and VBE variation with batch and temperature easily swamp any error from calling the output impedance infinite. But, it's there in the model, and if for some reason you do want a more complete academic answer, then you can include estimates and refine the circuit in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks for the long explanation. I went into this convinced that there must be simple proof for a circuit like this but sounds like that is not the case. As I said we do know all values, including beta (100 is OK).

Comment: About the only thing I would add is that the “no base current” assumption only holds outside of saturation. So first look at it as-if it wasn’t saturated, and if the CE voltage is low enough, re-analyze, now assuming saturation and a BE diode.

Comment: You've touched on perhaps the biggest flaw in my question, which is that there is a non-linear device in the circuit.

Comment: Of course the biggest assumption I didn't state is whether the circuit is linear or saturated. If this is a biassed transistor to be used as an amplifier, then the linear assumption is probably sound. But if we calacuate according to either assumption, then only one will be consistent.

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Really proving with formulas can be a bit complicated ...

Here is a Maple sheet that would do it ... for two cases.
Linear calculus and non-linear calculus (only for BE junction).

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is a resolution with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip), DC analysis.

Very near voltages ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree to everythig written by Neil_UK in his contribution.

Nevertheless, two remarks which might help to simplify the whole process:

(1) The uncertainty regarding beta (resp. base current) cab drastically be reduced (plays a minor role) when the quiescent current I1 through the base divider is large enough. That means: The base current through R1 should be 1/10 of I1 or even less. In this case, the voltage produced by the divider can be regarded as sufficiently "stiff" (which is a necessary precondition for the efficiency of the following point 2).

(2) When the emitter resistor RE is sufficiently large (app. in the range of 0.1RL), the negative feedback provided by RE (loop gain: Transconductance gm multiplied by RE) makes the whole system relatively unsensitive to the VBE uncertainty.

That means: The influence of VBE on the collector current is drasticaly reduced and it is not very important if you choose a value of VBE=0.65V or VBE=0.7V for calculating the current Ie resp. Ic.

However, there is a general rule in connection with circuit modifications:

When we try to improve one specific property of the circuit (example:  sensitivity to tolerances and other uncertainties), we must accept that another property will become worse.

That means in our case that we have to "pay something" for such a stabilization effect: The gain goes down and the usable dynamic range of the amplifier is reduced (smaller "quasi-linear" region of the transfer characteristic).

Comment: A higher value for RE doesn't reduce temperature caused dc bias variation. Changing RE, changes re in proportion (Loop gain RE/re stays the same) and the designer has to then change RC to bring the collector back to mid-supply leaving the gain unchanged and it is the dc gain (RC/RE, ignoring re) which determines the amount of temperature caused collector bias change. Or put another way, for a given voltage supply, it is the value of the emitter voltage which determines the amount of temperature caused collector bias variation. I usually try and keep Av to below 10 for a 20V supply .....

Comment: ..... or below 5 for a 10 V supply (when not resorting to emitter by-passing) which puts the emitter voltage at a minimum of 1 V.

Comment: Quote: "changing RE changes re in proportion.." . But this applies only when you modify RE in a given circuit without touching the rest of the circuit.  An experienced designer would - of course - try to keep Ic (and, hence, re=1/gm) constant by changing the bias circuitry correpondingly.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Increasing RE and simultaneously increasing the base bias (and emitter bias) to keep Ic (and re) constant does indeed reduce collector bias variation due to Vbe temperature changes but this is due to the resulting reduction in gain (and resulting increase in dc emitter voltage) rather than having a large RE per se which you seem to agree doesn't, by itself, reduce collector bias temperature dependence.  Maybe you could add this to your answer to clear up the ambiguity.

Comment: OK - I followed your advice.